# How should users with low permissions indicate that an answer doesn't work?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Recently, a new answer popped up for a ["resolved" question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78410/how-can-i-get-the-buttons-back-on-the-left-side-in-gnome):

> I can't get this to work! I've tried to do it manually and in terminal but nothing works. [...]
>
> (why cant i post comments!?)

Like a good worker bee, I immediately reported it as `not an answer`, but — as it turns out — the existing answers did not actually work anymore. So I updated the accepted answer.

The problem is: that wayward commenter had no correct way express the inadequacy of existing solutions. They had only 1 reputation point. What should low-rep users do in this situation?

Comment: 1. The older answer you edited works for 11.04 and 11.10. As such, the new answer you edited in works for only 12.04.
2. It is a dupe of another question which has updated answers for most of the versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone found a problem, didn't have the reputation, but misused the site in good faith, allowing it to get on your radar, and then we found the duplicate, fixed it, updated it, merged it, and then made the site better for the win. What's the problem here? :)

It might not be pretty or an ideally designed workflow, but it does seem to actually work!

- Out of curiosity, we should investigate a query to search for new posts with things like "doesn't work" from low rep users and see if we can find some low hanging fruit of this exact sort of thing, I'm willing to bet it'd be a nice "things to update" list.

Answer (score 4):

Addressing your question, the users who don't have privilege to cast vote can provide their feedback by clicking whether the post is useful or otherwise.

[image]

It is my understanding that the moderators and the 10k+ users can see anonymous feedback on posts.